# Php class inside connection close or class close?

Tags: php, function, class, pdo

i have php class `USER` and `Database` class im doing `10000 users app`, and that user will be query `3-4 times` a day minumum . my class base and function base here them looking yet for thats `have any problem ?` or need `any fix ?`

`MY db class`

```
class Database
{   
    private $host = "";
    private $db_name = "";
    private $username = "";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;    
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {

             print'{"success": "0","message": "Service Error, Please try again later "}';

        }


        return $this->conn;
    }


}
```

`Also my USER class here`

```
<?php

require_once('dbconfig.php');

class USER
{   

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function updateProduct($name,$code,$description,$quantity,$price,$specialwarning,$productID)
    {
        try
        {


            $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE Products SET productCode='$code',productName='$name',productDescription='$description',specialWarning='$specialwarning',productQuantity='$quantity',productPrice='$price' WHERE ID=$productID");
            $stmt2->execute();

            echo'{"success": "1", "message": "Product Updated"}';


            return true;


        }
            catch(PDOException $e)
        {



    }
     $this->conn = null;  // HERE I DID NULL FOR DISABLE MAX CONNECTIONS
}

}
```

`AND HER MY updateproduct.php`

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$code = $_REQUEST['code'];
$description = $_REQUEST['description'];
$quantity = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
$price = $_REQUEST['price'];
$specialwarning = $_REQUEST['specialwarning'];
$productID = $_REQUEST['productID'];



include_once 'class.user.php';

$user = new USER($DB_con);

if($user->updateProduct($name,$code,$description,$quantity,$price,$specialwarning,$productID))
 {

}
 else
 {

 } 

?>
```

Can you check my codes is `good class` for `big users ?` and good connection `returns ?` Can i add something ? or need `any fix ?`Also need to `close class ?`

Thanks

Comment: This question must be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You have `a serious` sql injection `problem`, you should `use` prepared `statements instead`.

Comment: @jeroen thanks dude how can i do that ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @jeroen i need to do   $stmt->bind_param("s", $city); like ?

Comment: No, you should check the manual.

Comment: @jeroen ty i will do also u see another fix ? in my codes ?